# Marshaling C# struct into native C library

Tags: c#, c, struct, shared-libraries, marshalling

I'm currently writing a [*NTRUMLS C#*](https://github.com/FractalGlobal/NTRUMLS-Sharp) wrapper for the [*NTRUMLS C*](https://github.com/NTRUOpenSourceProject/NTRUMLS) library.  I'm running into an issue where I don't believe i'm marshaling the parameters data correctly through the foreign function interface that map to the C library entry points.

Here's the specific foreign function interface I'm using in `ffi.cs`.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using NTRUMLS.Params;

namespace NTRUMLS.ffi {
public static class ffi {

    [DllImport("ntrumls")]
    public static extern int pq_gen_key(ParamSet p, out IntPtr privkey_blob_len, out byte[] privkey_blob, out IntPtr pubkey_blob_len, out byte[] pubkey_blob);
  }
}
```

The specific ParamSet Struct i'm passing in `param.cs`, which I believe might be specifically causing the issue.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace NTRUMLS.Params {

[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public enum ParamSetId {
    Xxx20140508401,
    Xxx20140508439,
    Xxx20140508593,
    Xxx20140508743,

    Xxx20151024401,
    Xxx20151024443,
    Xxx20151024563,
    // Xxx20151024509,
    Xxx20151024743,
    Xxx20151024907,
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ParamSet {


    ParamSetId id;

    IntPtr name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    byte[] oid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    byte n_bits;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    byte q_bits;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    ushort n;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    sbyte p;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]
    long q;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]
    long b_s;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]
    long b_t;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]
    long norm_bound_s;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]
    long norm_bound_t;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    byte d1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    byte d2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    byte d3;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    ushort padded_n;

    public ushort get_n() {
        return n;
    }

    public sbyte get_p() {
        return p;
    }

    public byte get_d1() {
        return d1;
    }

    public byte get_d2() {
        return d2;
    }

    public byte get_d3() {
        return d3;
    }

    public uint product_form_bytes() {
        return (uint)(4 * (d1 + d2 + d3));
    }

    public uint polynomial_bytes() {
        return (uint)(padded_n * 8);
    }

    public uint privkey_packed_bytes() {
        return (uint)(5 + 2 * ((2 * ( d1 + d2 + d3) * n_bits + 7) / 8) + ((n +4) / 5));
    }

    public uint pubkey_packed_bytes() {
        return (uint)(5 + (n * q_bits + 7) / 8 + 64);
    }

    public ParamSet (ParamSetId ID, IntPtr NAME, byte[] OID, byte N_BITS, byte Q_BITS, ushort N, sbyte P, long Q, long B_S, long B_T, long NORM_BOUND_S, long NORM_BOUND_T, byte D1, byte D2, byte D3, ushort PADDED_N) {
        id = ID;
        name = NAME;
        oid = OID;
        n_bits = N_BITS;
        q_bits = Q_BITS;
        n = N;
        p = P;
        q = Q;;
        b_s = B_S;
        b_t = B_T;
        norm_bound_s = NORM_BOUND_S;
        norm_bound_t = NORM_BOUND_T;
        d1 = D1;
        d2 = D2;
        d3 = D3;
        padded_n = PADDED_N;
    }


}

public static class ParamSets {

    /// <summary>
    /// 256 bit security parameter
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly ParamSet Xxx20140508_743 = new ParamSet(
        ParamSetId.Xxx20140508743,
        Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto("Xxx20140508743"),
        new byte[] {0xff, 0xff, 0xfc},
        10,
        20,
        743,
        3,
        1 << 20,
        336,
        112,
        (1 << 19) - 336,
        (1 << 19) - 112,
        11,
        11,
        15,
        768);
   }
}
```

And here's the wrapper itself `NTRUMLSWrapper.cs`.

```
using NTRUMLS.ffi;
using NTRUMLS.Params;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NTRUMLS.Library {

public static class NTRUMLSWrapper {

    public static KeyPair generate_keys(ParamSet param) {
        int pub_len = 0;
        int priv_len = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Param N: " + param.get_n());
        Console.WriteLine("Param P: " + param.get_p());
        Console.WriteLine("Param D1: " + param.get_d1());
        Console.WriteLine("Param D2: " + param.get_d2());
        Console.WriteLine("Param D3: " + param.get_d3());

        GCHandle pub_len_handle = GCHandle.Alloc(pub_len);
        GCHandle priv_len_handle = GCHandle.Alloc(priv_len);

        IntPtr privkey_blob_len = (IntPtr)pub_len_handle;
        IntPtr pubkey_blob_len = (IntPtr)priv_len_handle;

        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(param);

        IntPtr paramater = (IntPtr)handle;

        byte[] pv = new byte[priv_len];
        byte[] pb = new byte[pub_len];

    //    GCHandle pv_handle = GCHandle.Alloc(pv);
    //    GCHandle pb_handle = GCHandle.Alloc(pb);

        var result = ffi.ffi.pq_gen_key(param, out privkey_blob_len, out pv, out pubkey_blob_len, out pb);

        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result + " Private Key BLob Length: " + priv_len + " Public Key Blob Lengh: " + pub_len);



       if (result != 0)
          Console.WriteLine("We got problems");

         byte[] privatekey_blob = new byte[privkey_blob_len.ToInt64()];
         byte[] pubkey_blob = new byte[pubkey_blob_len.ToInt64()];

         result = ffi.ffi.pq_gen_key(param, out privkey_blob_len, out privatekey_blob, out pubkey_blob_len, out pubkey_blob);

        if (result != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("We got problems");

       Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result.ToString() + " Private Key BLob Length: " + privkey_blob_len + " Public Key Blob Lengh: " + pubkey_blob_len);

        // byte[] privkeyBytes = new byte[priv_len.ToInt32()];
        // byte[] pubkeyBytes = new byte[pub_len.ToInt32()];



        return new KeyPair(new PrivateKey(pubkey_blob), new PublicKey(privatekey_blob));;

    }

}


public struct PrivateKey {
    byte[] ffi_key;

    public PrivateKey (byte[] bytes) {
        ffi_key = bytes;
    }

    public byte[] get_bytes() {
        return ffi_key;
    }
}

public struct PublicKey {
    byte[] ffi_key;

    public PublicKey (byte[] bytes) {
        ffi_key = bytes;
    }

    public byte[] get_bytes() {
        return ffi_key;
    }
}

 public struct KeyPair {

    PublicKey publicKey;
    PrivateKey privateKey;

    public KeyPair(PrivateKey privKey, PublicKey pubkey)
    {
        publicKey = pubkey;
        privateKey = privKey;
    }

    public PublicKey getPublic()
    {
        return publicKey;
    }

    public PrivateKey getPrivate()
    {
        return privateKey;
    }

  }

}
```

And the `Program.cs` to run the key gen test.

```
using System;
using NTRUMLS.Library;
using NTRUMLS.Params;

namespace NTRUMLS
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        KeyPair keypair = NTRUMLSWrapper.generate_keys(ParamSets.Xxx20140508_743);

        Console.WriteLine("Generated Keys!");

        // TODO Sign, than Verify to confirm test

    }
}
}
```

Here's the header function of the C function I'm marshaling into

in `pqntrusign.h`

```
int
pq_gen_key(
PQ_PARAM_SET  *params,
size_t        *privkey_blob_len,
unsigned char *privkey_blob,
size_t        *pubkey_blob_len,
unsigned char *pubkey_blob);
```

in `params.h` and `params.c`

```
enum _PQ_PARAM_SET_ID {
XXX_20140508_401,
XXX_20140508_439,
XXX_20140508_593,
XXX_20140508_743,

XXX_20151024_401,
XXX_20151024_443,
XXX_20151024_563,
//XXX_20151024_509,
XXX_20151024_743,
XXX_20151024_907,
};


struct _PQ_PARAM_SET {
PQ_PARAM_SET_ID  id;          /* parameter set id */
const char       *name;       /* human readable name */
const uint8_t    OID[3];      /* OID */
uint8_t          N_bits;      /* ceil(log2(N)) */
uint8_t          q_bits;      /* ceil(log2(q)) */
uint16_t         N;           /* ring degree */
int8_t           p;           /* message space prime */
int64_t          q;           /* ring modulus */
int64_t          B_s;         /* max norm of f*a convolution */
int64_t          B_t;         /* max norm of g*a convolution */
int64_t          norm_bound_s;/* q/2 - B_s */
int64_t          norm_bound_t;/* q/2 - B_t */
uint8_t          d1;          /* Product form +1/-1 counts */
uint8_t          d2;
uint8_t          d3;
uint16_t         padded_N;    /* # Polynomial coefficients for Karatsuba */
};
```

I believe the current problem is with the `ParamSet struct`, and matching the name attribute properly with the C struct `const char*name` pointer attribute. However, i'm not entirely sure that's the case.

I modified the NTRUMLS C `pqntrusign.c` source file to print out to a log.txt and logs the variables i'm passing.  Here's the snippet i added in the very beginning of the `int pq_gen_key` function.

```
 FILE * fp;

 fp = fopen ("log.txt", "a+");
 fprintf(fp, "Logging made it here variables priv_blob_len_pointer %i pub_blob_len_pointer %i priv_blob_len %i pub_blob_len %i privkey %x pubkey %x \n", privkey_blob_len, pubkey_blob_len, *privkey_blob_len, *pubkey_blob_len, privkey_blob, pubkey_blob);

 fprintf(fp, "Logging param ID: %i Oid %x : N: %i Q: %i P %i Padded N: %i D1: %i D2: %i D3: %i \n", P->id, P->OID, P->N, P->q, P->p, P->padded_N, P->d1, P->d2, P->d3);



if(!P || !privkey_blob_len || !pubkey_blob_len)
{
  return PQNTRU_ERROR;
}

N = P->N;
padN = P->padded_N;
q = P->q;
p = P->p;
d1 = P->d1;
d2 = P->d2;
d3 = P->d3;

fprintf(fp, "Logging Local N: %i Q: %i P %i Padded N: %i D1: %i D2: %i D3: %i \n", N, q, p, padN, d1, d2, d3);

fclose(fp);
```

I'm using Fedora 23 x64 so the current libntrumls.so uploaded on the NTRUMLS-Sharp github was compiled with that snippet added.

Output from C# Console

```
Param N: 743
Param P: 3
Param D1: 11
Param D2: 11
Param D3: 15
Result: -1 Private Key BLob Length: 0 Public Key Blob Lengh: 0
We got problems
We got problems
Result: -1 Private Key BLob Length: 3 Public Key Blob Lengh: 11
Generated Keys!
```

Output from log.txt

```
Logging made it here variables priv_blob_len_pointer -923442424 pub_blob_len_pointer -923442432 priv_blob_len -994004096 pub_blob_len -994004064 privkey c8f56510 pubkey f0b0b 
Logging param ID: 3 Oid c8f56528 : N: 0 Q: 42678032 P 19 Padded N: 0 D1: 11 D2: 0 D3: 0 
Logging Local N: 0 Q: 42678032 P 19 Padded N: 0 D1: 11 D2: 0 D3: 0 
Logging made it here variables priv_blob_len_pointer -923442424 pub_blob_len_pointer -923442432 priv_blob_len -994003392 pub_blob_len -994003352 privkey c8f56510 pubkey f0b0b 
Logging param ID: 3 Oid c8f56528 : N: 0 Q: 42678032 P 19 Padded N: 0 D1: 11 D2: 0 D3: 0 
Logging Local N: 0 Q: 42678032 P 19 Padded N: 0 D1: 11 D2: 0 D3: 0
```

**EDIT:**
Another interesting thing to note is param ID logged as 3 is correct, since the enum `Xxx20140508743` is 3, and D1 is correct as 11.  But every time i run the function the output logged for OID is different, when it's a set 3 byte array in my `ParamSet.Xxx20140508_743`.  This leads me to believe the error is in marshaling `const char *name`, which is throwing the rest off.

Below is a another output of log.txt for comparison (this is also with the added "\0" to `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto("Xxx20140508743\0")`

```
Logging made it here variables priv_blob_len_pointer 982750168 pub_blob_len_pointer 982750160 priv_blob_len -960449664 pub_blob_len -960449632 privkey 3a9395e0 pubkey f0b0b 
Logging param ID: 3 Oid 3a9395f8 : N: 0 Q: 38160144 P 19 Padded N: 0 D1: 11 D2: 0 D3: 0 
Logging Local N: 0 Q: 38160144 P 19 Padded N: 0 D1: 11 D2: 0 D3: 0 
Logging made it here variables priv_blob_len_pointer 982750168 pub_blob_len_pointer 982750160 priv_blob_len -960448960 pub_blob_len -960448920 privkey 3a9395e0 pubkey f0b0b 
Logging param ID: 3 Oid 3a9395f8 : N: 0 Q: 38160144 P 19 Padded N: 0 D1: 11 D2: 0 D3: 0 
Logging Local N: 0 Q: 38160144 P 19 Padded N: 0 D1: 11 D2: 0 D3: 0
```

I don't believe the Windows dll is working yet.  If someone can't see the problem immediately in my code, or error log, the directions to compile and test everything are in the NTRUMLS C# README file.

Thank you for taking the time to read this question!  I know it's long and descriptive, but I wasn't quite sure how to narrow it down without providing all the information since I spent a lot of time searching the forums and modifying my code to get this far.

Best Regards

Comment: An enum can be different sizes 1,2,4,8 bytes so check you c language compiler for default size.  The size can be set in c# to match c language.  Make sure 'name' ends with a '\0'.  Try :  Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto("Xxx20140508743\0"),

Comment: Unfortunately adding "\0" didn't fix it. However, another interesting note to make is the param ID enum seems to be marshaling correctly since Xxx2014050874 is the third enum in the list, and the log output shows param ID to be 3, as well as D1 to be 11 which is correct. But what is interesting is Oid changes every time the function is run, and should be a set const 3 byte array. I'll edit my post to show the different log output

Comment: Variables are being passed properly from c# to c, but the return is failing because you corrupted the execution stack.  In .h pq_gen_key parameter list contains 5 pointers so in c# the DllImport must contain 5 IntPtr.  Then take ParamSet p and use Marshal.StructureToPtr to get the IntPtr.

Comment: Brilliant mate! I you were spot on about the struct and the rest needing to be IntPtr as well.

Comment: You can't pass local variables that are on the execution stack to a dll which requires variables to be global (static).  The AllocHGlobal allocates memory in global space and that is why the ParamSet is now working.  You have similar issue with your byte[].  You must use AllocHGlobal to allocate global memory for your byte array.  Then use Marshal.Copy() to copy byte[] to allocated global memory.  Again in DllImport your parameter is IntPtr like I said earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all works now!

Marshaling the params struct looks like this

```
        IntPtr parameter = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(param));

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(param, parameter, false);
```

below is the final function working.

```
    public static KeyPair generate_keys(ParamSet param) {
        uint pub_len = 0;
        uint priv_len = 0;

        IntPtr privkey_blob_len = new IntPtr(priv_len);
        IntPtr pubkey_blob_len = new IntPtr(pub_len);

        IntPtr parameter = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(param));

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(param, parameter, false);

        IntPtr pv_ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr pb_ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

        var result = ffi.ffi.pq_gen_key(parameter, out privkey_blob_len, pv_ptr, out pubkey_blob_len, pb_ptr);

        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result + " Private Key BLob Length: " + privkey_blob_len.ToInt32() + " Public Key Blob Lengh: " + pubkey_blob_len);


       if (result != 0)
          Console.WriteLine("We got problems");


        pv_ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(privkey_blob_len.ToInt32());
        pb_ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(pubkey_blob_len.ToInt32());


        result = ffi.ffi.pq_gen_key(parameter, out privkey_blob_len, pv_ptr, out pubkey_blob_len, pb_ptr);

        if (result != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("We got problems");

       Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result.ToString() + " Private Key BLob Length: " + privkey_blob_len + " Public Key Blob Lengh: " + pubkey_blob_len);

        byte[] privkeyBytes = new byte[privkey_blob_len.ToInt32()];
        byte[] pubkeyBytes = new byte[pubkey_blob_len.ToInt32()];

        Marshal.Copy(pv_ptr, privkeyBytes, 0, privkey_blob_len.ToInt32());
        Marshal.Copy(pb_ptr, pubkeyBytes, 0, pubkey_blob_len.ToInt32());


        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pv_ptr);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pb_ptr);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(parameter);


        return new KeyPair(new PrivateKey(privkeyBytes), new PublicKey(pubkeyBytes));

    }
```

And my ffi

```
public static class ffi {

    [DllImport("ntrumls")]
    public static extern int pq_gen_key(IntPtr p, out IntPtr privkey_blob_len, IntPtr privkey_blob, out IntPtr pubkey_blob_len, IntPtr pubkey_blob);


}
```